# Set a hotkey press event for the form

Tags: powershell

Use the following code to set hotkey press event  for the form, but when the hotkey is pressed, the system has an alarm sound, why?

In addition, how to set multiple modifier keys, For example ctrl+alt+shift+Q

```
$form1_KeyDown = [System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler]{
    #Event Argument: $_ = [System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs]
    if ($_.Alt -and $_.KeyCode -eq 'Q')
    {
        Write-Host 'Alt-Q pressed'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not know why you get a system beep when pressing a hotkey, but it may have to do with the way you add the KeyEventHandler to the form.

Using `$form1.Add_KeyDown({..})` gives me no problem whatsoever:

```
$form1.Add_KeyDown({
    # create a small array to capture the modifier keys used
    $modifiers = @()
    if ($_.Shift)   { $modifiers += "Shift" }
    if ($_.Alt)     { $modifiers += "Alt" }
    if ($_.Control) { $modifiers += "Control" }
    # using that array, build part of the output text
    $modkeys = ''
    if ($modifiers.Count) {
        $modkeys = '{0} ' -f ($modifiers -join ' + ')
    }

    # instead of building up a string 'Shift + Control + Alt', like above, you can also use 
    # the $_.Modifiers property and replace the commas by a plus sign like this:
    # $modkeys = $_.Modifiers -replace ', ', ' + '

    # these are the keys you want to react upon as example
    # here all keys pressed simply do the same thing, namely display what was pressed,
    # so we can shorten the code to simply test if any of the keys in the 
    # array correspond with the key the user pressed.

    if ('Q','A','F1','Escape','NumLock' -contains $_.KeyCode) {

        # we create the output string by making use of the '-f' Format operator in POwershell.
        # you can read more about that here for instance:
        # https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.powershell-using-the-f-format-operator.aspx
        Write-Host ('{0}{1} pressed' -f $modkeys, $_.KeyCode)

        # The same could have been done with something like:
        # Write-Host ($modkeys + ' ' + $_.KeyCode + ' pressed')
        # or
        # Write-Host "$modkeys $($_.KeyCode) pressed"
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I need to take the time to understand it, it would be better if there is a shorter code.

Comment: @tianyi Shorter code does not always mean it is more understandable. (in fact, the opposite is often true). Anyway, I have edited my answer for you and put in a lot of comment lines to help you understand what happens. Comments are not code and you're welcome to delete whatever comment you feel is superfluous. Hope that helps